# How to reach Promise reject option in a Google Cloud Function used as a Dialogflow webhook?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, request-promise

I'm building a Dialogflow chatbot that uses a Google Cloud Function as a webhook, with node.js and request-promise-native and without using Firebase or Google Actions. My webhook works fine for fetching and returning the data I want from an external API (Promise resolved), but now I have problems trying to code error handling with Promise reject.

Here is a snippet of code showing what I'm trying to do. With a deliberately wrong URL, the code jumps to the .catch block without ever going to the Promise reject option, and the cloud function log shows the error message "Unhandled rejection".

```
function searchMyData(agent) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var myUrl = 'deliberately wrong to trigger rejection';

        // Make the HTTP request with request-promise-native
        // https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise

        var options = {
            uri: myUrl,
            headers: {
                'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise-Native'
            },
            json: true
        };

        rpn(options)
            .then((json) => {
                if(json) {
                    // Whole bunch of code for getting the desired data 
                    // and resolving the Promise
                    // This part works
                    var result = agent.add('Here is your data');
                    resolve(result); // Promise resolved
                }
                else { // This block is not run, why?
                    // Reject Promise and return error message to Dialogflow
                    console.log('Promise rejected');
                    var rejectMessage = 'Sorry, an error occurred.';
                    agent.add(rejectMessage);
                    reject(rejectMessage);
                }
            }) // .then end
            .catch((err) => { 
                console.log('In .catch block'); // This is run
                throw new Error('err.message from .catch: '+ err.message); // This is run
            }); // .catch end
    }); // Promise end
} // searchMyData end
```

I am unclear as to how to structure the code to make it run the Promise rejection when there is an error. The structure used here is what I've seen in tutorials, with the Promise resolved in the if block and rejected in the else block, all within .then, and followed by .catch. But my code never reaches the else block.

Or, alternatively, is it possible to leave out the Promise rejected option altogether, or will it create hidden problems somewhere down the line? All I really want to do in case the webhook does not work is return an error message to the user in Dialogflow (and log the error internally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on Promises. Rejected promises are returned as the second parameter in the then block.

```
rpn(options)
        .then((json) => {
            if(json) {
                // Whole bunch of code for getting the desired data 
                // and resolving the Promise
                // This part works
                var result = agent.add('Here is your data');
                resolve(result); // Promise resolved
            }
}, error => { // This block will be run on promise rejection

                console.log('Promise rejected');
                var rejectMessage = 'Sorry, an error occurred.';
                agent.add(rejectMessage);
                reject(rejectMessage);
            }
        }) // .then end
```

Comment: Thanks! That works for getting rid of "uncaught" error messages in the log. I am still not getting rejectMessage through to Dialogflow, but on closer inspection this seems to be due a fixed request timeout of 5 seconds for webhook responses. I'll have to figure out some kind of workaround for this, but at least now I don't have uncaught errors floating around.

Comment: To follow up, I made a dummy version of the code to avoid the external API webhook timeout that may be masking any actual problems. I'm still getting an "Unhandled rejection" error in the log, although the example above got rid of "Uncaught exception". My question now is whether unhandled rejections are something to worry about and what should I do about them? I'm trying to handle the rejection by generating an error: 
reject(Error('Promise rejected'));
but apparently this is not enough.

Comment: If you are thrwoing an error, you need to catch it with a catch block. Promises work well, but error handling is best done with try catch and async await. You can wrap your promise in a try catch block, so the errors will always be handled in the catch block.

Comment: Thanks again! I do have a catch block as in the example code, but it looks like just throwing an error is not working. I will have to look into async/await as well. In the actual webhook, if I try to simulate an error situation, the webhook request simply times out before any other error messages are logged. I can always provide an error message to the user via Dialogflow's own console, but it still seems like this is leaving an unresolved and unrejected Promise floating around somewhere. Though maybe the Google Cloud Function deals with them behind the scenes somehow?

Comment: Your catch block catches the error from rpn().. . But you must be calling searchMyData() somewhere which returns a promise.When this promise(from searchMyData) is rejected, you are not handling it. That's why you see a unhandled rejection error. In general a catch block must be used on the bottom most function in the callstack. That will always catch the topmost error and your program will not face any crashes or warnings.